# Why is my leaflet control appearing in the bottom left corner of my map when I specified a postion of 'topleft'?

Tags: leaflet

I created a custom control and added it to my Leaflet map. Why does it appear in the bottom left corner even though I specify a position of 'topleft'?

```
  L.Control.Custom = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
      position: "topleft"
    },
    onAdd: function(myMap) {
      // Add reference to map
      var div = L.DomUtil.create(
        "div",
        "leaflet-bar info hit-count-control"
      );
      return div;
    },
    onRemove: function(myMap) {
      // Remove reference from map
      delete myMap.hitCountControl;
    },
});
```

Comment: You have specified position `position: "bottomleft"` not `topleft`

Comment: Seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/zmvxqs3u/

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your control options wiht `L.setOptions(this, options);`:

```
  L.Control.Custom = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
      position: "bottomleft"
    },

    initialize(options) {
        L.setOptions(this, options);
    },
    onAdd: function(myMap) {
      // Add reference to map
      var div = L.DomUtil.create(
        "div",
        "leaflet-bar info hit-count-control"
      );
      return div;
    },
    onRemove: function(myMap) {
      // Remove reference from map
      delete myMap.hitCountControl;
    },
});
```

```
new L.Control.Custom({position: 'topleft'});
```

Comment: sorry my fail, it has to be `initialize(options) {`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by this correction? What is the new code you are suggesting? Cheers

Comment: I have already updated the code above. Here is a example https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/rk53v9Ly/. When you create the Contorl and you add args (options) to it, like `position` it will overwrite the default.

Comment: In that example, the control is in the top left even thought the code specifies 'bottomleft'